# How do I get h1 above border

Tags: html, css, psd

I'm coding a free PSD to HTML and everything is fine except one thing - I have no idea how to get something like this:

[Slice from PSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2evY.png)

How do I get h1 above border so it can cover a part of it? Can it be done with pure CSS or do I have use JS?

Comment: Did you try with a negative margin? Don't forget to send h1 as display inline instead of block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{
  background:white;
}
fieldset {
      display: block;
      margin: 20px 1%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 0 auto;
      padding: 15px 0;
      border: 0;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 98%;
      background:white;
      color:black;
}

fieldset:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
}

legend {
     display: table; 
     min-width: 0px;
     max-width: 70%;
     position: relative;
     margin: auto;
     padding: 5px 20px;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: center;
}

fieldset div{
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  width:50%;
  //border:thin red solid;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
    <fieldset>
        <legend align="center" >About Us</legend>
          <div>
            When You work with us... content
          </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Are you looking for this?

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncv8H/73/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: doing with `<form>` just doesn't feel semantic to me, Is there any other way ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for :) But i have one more question - what property should I change to increase left and right margin from text to border?

Comment: @Mahaveersharma..  i have updated the answer. please check.

Comment: JSfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jengeLv6/) - Right now I have something like this and it works great, but i have to change the borders on left and right from '<legend>' to fit longer text. How can I do that?

Comment: Ok, I've changed margins to smaller ones and I've made another class for other sections and it's looking good, thank you for all the help :) Updated fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jengeLv6/1/)

Comment: sorry. didn't get you. if you have longer text then it will be fitted as well. and you want to change the border ? i didn't get you in that.

Comment: so you got your solution based on your requirements?

Answer (score 3):

```css
legend {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 3em);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Test</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for :) But i have one more question - what property should I change to increase left and right margin from text to border?

Comment: legend {padding-left: X; padding-right:Y}, and for centered the text margin-left: clac(50% - Z), where Z = [lenght of title] / 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some regular tags (not against semantic) and flex you can do it:

```css
div {
  magin: 2em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border: solid;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: -0.6em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: solid;
  margin: auto -3px auto 2em;
}
h1:before {
  margin: auto 2em auto -3px;
}
p {
  padding: 1em;
}
/* do i see through ? */

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left, gray,yellow,purple,gold,pink,tomato);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You might be looking for this

```
<div>
   <h1>Some Text</h1>
    <p>Some text also</p>
</div>
```

And styles are

```
div{
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;  
}
div h1{
    background:#fff;
    margin-top:-20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
```

CSS is given in the link

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r45864om/)

Comment: That's also a good solution, but when I delete background from h1 the border is visible. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: No, there's no solution.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).